# Flutter Firestore stream does not update when using order by clause

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am returning a stream from firestore using the below:

```
Stream<CompletedExerciseList> getExerciseStream(String uid, {int limit}) {

Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots;

try {
  CollectionReference exerciseCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).collection('completed_exercise');

  if (limit != null) {
    snapshots = exerciseCollection.orderBy('startTime', descending: false).orderBy('name', descending: true).limit(limit).snapshots();
  } else {
    snapshots = exerciseCollection.orderBy('startTime', descending: false).orderBy('name', descending: true).snapshots();
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}

return snapshots.map((list) => CompletedExerciseList(list.documents.map((doc) => ExerciseModel.fromMap(doc.data)).toList()));
}
```

The above method returns a stream on widget build but when the documents in the collection are updated the stream is not updated. However if I remove the orderBy clause the stream updates correctly when documents are added/deleted from the collection. So the below code works, however I need to be able to order and limit the results of the snapshot.

```
Stream<CompletedExerciseList> getExerciseStream(String uid, {int limit}) {

Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots;

try {
  CollectionReference exerciseCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).collection('completed_exercise');

  if (limit != null) {
    snapshots = exerciseCollection.limit(limit).snapshots();
    } else {
    snapshots = exerciseCollection.snapshots();
    }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}

return snapshots.map((list) => CompletedExerciseList(list.documents.map((doc) => ExerciseModel.fromMap(doc.data)).toList()));
}
```

For both scenarios no error is printed to my console. I'm using Android Studio with the Flutter SDK.

Comment: Doesn't console give error like, index is required with a link to create index when you use the order by? When you order, filter using multiple fields, a composite index has to be created. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#queries_supported_by_composite_indexes

Comment: I figured an index was required, but I'm not getting the error message in my console log.

Comment: I believe you are using StreamBuilder, there if you check snapshot.hasError and print the error, you should get the error message there. If not, once use, future to perform same query instead of stream and calling that future should give an error

Comment: You need to create composite indexes for these two fields "startTime" and "name" using the collection id "completed_exercise"

Comment: If I add `.limit(1)` to my firestore snapshots query then Stream's listen function is not called. Kindly share your suggestion, if any. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check for snapshot errors on your StreamBuilder. As for sorting your Firestore data, you need to set up an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).

Comment: Spent a couple of hours without any solution, until you pointed out to debug the error logs and add an index to the key of order by clause.